# Azure VM with SQL pricing calculator vs estimated price in sizing screen

Tags: azure

If I use the Azure Price calculator, I get the following price for a VM **without** SQL

[image: Azure Pricing without SQL]

If I add SQL the price changes to

[image]

Which is what I would expect.

If I create a VM via the portal based on the SQL `SQL Server 2014 SP2 Standard on Windows Server 2012 R2` template, the estimated price is as follows

[image]

How is the pay as you go SQL billed / purchased?

*I have just tried the newest SQL templated VM and it has the same issue*

Comment: I used to think that providing customers with incomprehensible licensing terms and cost models was the hallmark of large, mature and established software companies. More and more I see I'm mistaken in that. It is only when the companies themselves don't understand their own pricing and licensing scheme's anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> How is the pay as you go SQL billed/purchased?

When we create VM via the Azure portal, the prince just contains the OS fee.

When we use the Azure Price calculator, the prince contains OS and SQL license.

> Obtain a SQL Server image from the Marketplace and pay the per-minute
>   licensing rate of SQL Server. The SQL Server license fee is included
>   in the virtual machine image price as shown in the Virtual Machines
>   pricing page.

By the way, prices are estimates and are not intended as actual price quotes. Actual prices may vary depending upon the date of purchase, currency of payment, and type of agreement you enter with Microsoft.

For example, create an Azure VM and install SQL server on it, we will pay for OS license and SQL server license, pay for network traffic, and storage account usage and read/write.

More information about license and Azure VM, please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/licensing-faq/).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.